# Creating a string from some factors in a data frame - "For" loop seems unnecessary

Tags: r

I have a data frame, and make selections based on some of the factors.  I want a vector of names, created from the factor levels.  Hopefully this suffices to show the intent:

```
test.results <- list(
  First  = factor(c('A', 'B'), levels=c('A', 'B', 'C')),
  Second = factor(c('E', 'F'), levels=c('E', 'F', 'G')),
  Third  = factor(c('X', 'Y'), levels=c('X', 'Y', 'Z'))
  )

# cols <-  c('First', 'Third'); TestName(test.results, cols) should return c('A X', 'B Y')
```

Here is an implementation.  Is there a way to avoid the explicit 'for' loop?

```
TestName <- function(X, cols) {
  result <- character(length(cols))
  space <- '';
  for (i in cols) {
    result <- paste0(result, space, X[[i]]);
    space <- ' ';
  }
  return(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is not a data.frame in the example, but nevermind, the following will work regardless

`paste` is vectorized, so as the question stands there should be no need for `*apply` or `for loops`

```
testname <- function(x, .names){ do.call(paste, x[.names])}
testname(test.results, c('First','Third'))
## [1] "A X" "B Y"
```

You could add checks about whether `x` is a `list` and that `names` exist in `x`.

EDIT -- allowing `sep` to be set (or other variables) if you wished.

```
testname <- function(x, .names,...){ do.call(paste, c(x[.names], list(...)))}
testname(test.results, c('First','Third'), sep = '---')
## "A---X" "B---Y"
```

If your data was a `data.table` then you could do the following

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(test.results)

DT[, paste(First, Third)]
```

Or you could just stick with lists and data.frames and use `with` or `evalq`

```
evalq(paste(First,Third), test.results)
```

or

```
with(test.results, paste(First, Third))
```

Comment: Two in one, this allows the use of paste rather than paste0 and the space variable.  Thank you.

Comment: `paste0` is a shorthand for slightly faster version of `paste(..., sep='')`. I've now added an approach that will let you set `sep` to anything you want.

Comment: In the cases of data.table, what if the names, "First" and "Third" are in a variable?

Comment: The threee examples, `data.table`, `evalq`and `with` work best with the names as names, not character variables

Comment: The way things are now, I need to have the names in a character variable.  Fortunately, the do.call solution is perfect.  I'll look into data.table to see what it offers.

Comment: sorry @mnel, mine was in fact the indentical answer. I hadnt seen yours as I started typing.  went ahead and deleted it

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, No worries, have done the same thing in the past on many occasions